# What's different between the marketing-api optimization goal and FB BM's optimization goal?

Tags: facebook, optimization, facebook-ads-api

What's different between the marketing-api optimization goal and FB BM's optimization goal?

[Facebook marketing-api optimization_goal](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign)

```
{NONE, APP_INSTALLS, BRAND_AWARENESS, CLICKS, ENGAGED_USERS, EXTERNAL, EVENT_RESPONSES, IMPRESSIONS, LEAD_GENERATION, LINK_CLICKS, OFFER_CLAIMS, OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS, PAGE_ENGAGEMENT, PAGE_LIKES, POST_ENGAGEMENT, REACH, SOCIAL_IMPRESSIONS, VIDEO_VIEWS}
```

[FB BM's optimization goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt3fE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items shown on your screenshot aren't really optimization goals. They are campaign objectives. ([Here's the same screenshot in english](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HBFK.png))

Facebook's ads manager actually hides the real optimization goal and billing event. There's only a selectbox called *Optimisation for Advert Delivery* (in *Budget & pricing* section), which contains some (probably preferred ones) of available optimizations for the adset you're creating. 
Those values can be mapped to pairs of optimization goal + billing event. You can read the real values using Graph API.

Not all optimization goals are applicable for all objectives, so the values in the selectbox will differ based on selected objective. Allowed combinations are [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/validation/v2.5#bid_conversion)

Comment: Link to documentation is broken, the whole think might be outdated as fb usually doesn't support old api versions